# Оплата "ПО СЧЁТУ" или "ПРОТИВ СЧЁТА"

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно: оплатить аванс за работы ПО СЧЁТУ или ПРОТИВ СЧЁТА?

Раньше считалось: произвести оплату ПРОТИВ СЧЁТА, т. е. против документа, по его получении. Во всяком случае, инкассовые платежи осуществляются исключительно против документов, а не по счёту.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, о каких комментариях Вы говорите. Попробую представить своё понимание вопроса.

Произвести оплату ПРОТИВ СЧЁТА, ПРОТИВ ДОКУМЕНТОВ - это банковская операция по безналичному расчёту за товар инкассо (вы банку-инкассатору денежки - он вам документы на оборудование, которые дают право на получение этого оборудования, в том числе и счёт, уже вами оплаченный).

При расчёте за выполненную работу вы платите ПО СЧЁТУ-документу, где есть расценки, объём выполненных работ. И аванс тоже по счёту, вы ж не идёте в банк за оплатой? Поэтому деньги платите не против счёта, а против выполненной работы (по счёту).

ПРОТИВ в банковской терминологии - "вместо", обмен. Смысл как "ставлю деньги против документов", "шапку против рубахи" и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Это внутренний бухгалтерско-банковский жаргон, правила собственного русского языка обычно не регламентируют такие вещи. В среде профессоналов я, как человек не чуждый бухгалтерии, я бы вполне мог использовать "против счета", мне это понятно. Но если это надо сказать человеку далекому от таких тонкостей, то лучше "по счету". Остальное - у Людмилы.